# Android Studio: AbMob Banner won't display underneath webview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, constraints

I try to add an AdMob banner underneath a webview inside a fragment in Android Studio. 
Without constraints both adview and webview display in the upper left corner. With my constraints the webview fills the whole screen but the adview won't show up.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="46dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="552dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**

```
public class frag1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    WebView webView1 = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView1.loadUrl("https://seewettervorhersage.de/seewetter-2/");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    return v;
}
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

Comment: see logcat output to knowledge reason

Comment: 08-28 22:53:35.010 2927-2946/de.sewettervorhersage.seewetter W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
08-28 22:53:35.012 2927-2927/de.sewettervorhersage.seewetter W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: Error code 0 means Internal error, it generally occurs in newly created ads so  wait for few hours only

Answer (score 1):

Try Set your layout code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the same problem - the webview is filling the whole screen and the adview won't show up.

Comment: If I remove "android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"" from the adview the banner appears.